# How to redirect to splash page and allow for images to display in .htacess rule?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am using the following .htaccess rule to redirect all pages of my site to a splash pag. However, the image that should be on the splash page is not displaying. How do I add to this rule to allow for images to be displayed? Please correct the below rule if this is not the best thing to use in this situation.

```
RewriteEngine On

# temp redirect
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /index.html [R,L]`
```

So would this be the right way to do it?

```
RewriteEngine On
# temp redirect
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/coming-soon.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png)$
RewriteRule .* /coming-soon.html [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore files ending with .gif .jpg .png

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png)$
```

Comment: Please see above, can you please confirm the above code is the right way to do this?

Comment: Add **css** and **js** if you have them in your coming soon page